# Unable to alter font sizes as per to will!

Tags: fonts, posters

I'm trying to make a big poster where I want to write a lot of text. I have used the following codes as I have given a MWE below. In my `\documentclass` I'm using text font of 46pt. But now when I try to increase the font from 46pt to 56pt and 60pt, it doesn't work. Also it doesn't pick 42pt as well.
How do I increase my font size?

```
\documentclass[46pt, , landscape, margin=0mm, innermargin=0mm, blockverticalspace=5mm, colspace=0mm, subcolspace=-20mm]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=60in,paperheight=24in}
\begin{document}
\begin{columns} 
    \column{1}
    \block{}
    {       
        ABC1
    }

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, I am using Tikzposter environment. What should i do to increase my text font size?

Comment: Have you read the manual for `tikzposter`? It explicitly states which font sizes are supported

Comment: Take a look at the [`anyfontsize`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/anyfontsize) package (although this may or may not be a good thing to do).

Comment: You can find the documentation [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzposter/tikzposter.pdf).

Comment: So, according to this I cannot take a font size above 25pt???
Is this what it means to say?

Answer (score 6):

The maximum supported font size is 25pt. However, it's not really difficult to extend it. I just multiplied the sizes defined for 25pt by 46/25 (with rounding).

```
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  margin=0mm,
  innermargin=0mm,
  blockverticalspace=5mm,
  colspace=0mm,
  subcolspace=-20mm
]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=60in,paperheight=24in}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\renewcommand{\tiny}{\fontsize{22}{26.5}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\scriptsize}{\fontsize{26.5}{32}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{31}{38}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\small}{\fontsize{39}{46}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{46}{56}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\large}{\fontsize{55}{66}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\Large}{\fontsize{66}{73}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\LARGE}{\fontsize{80}{95}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\huge}{\fontsize{96}{115}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\Huge}{\fontsize{114}{137}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\block{}{
  ABC1
}

\block{}{
  \LARGE ABC1
}

\end{document}
```

I removed the `landscape` option, that would exchange page width and height. Also `lmodern` should be used, because it's fully scalable.

Comment: I have never used `tikzposter`,  but `a0poster` also redefines a bunch of skips (small, med, big, and above and below caption, display and display short).

Comment: Also, don't the new sizes need to be defined in `a0size.sty`, or else what is the point of `tikzposter` loading it?

Comment: @StrongBad You're right; it's probably better to avoid loading it. It's quite easy, actually.

Answer (score 2):

use the package `\usepackage{anyfontsize}`

Comment: Tried using that, doesn't work

Comment: @AbhijeetPattnayak - Please be specific as to what "doesn't work" entails.

Comment: Means when i tried adding the package and altering the sizes according to my wish, nothing happened.